# How to encrypt the source code of a sqlplus report

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql, sqlplus, obfuscation

I need to hide the code of a sqlplus report. It's used by an aplication for generating reports. I've tried oracle's **wrap** function, but it only hides the **PL/SQL** source code but not the **SQL*PLUS** source code.

Would you please recommend me a method to do it?.

Thank you.

Comment: You realistically can't (barring something like encrypting it and having a program runs that decrypts it before it gets passed to `SQL*Plus` but that likely just moves the problem around).  You can move any sensitive logic into stored procedures and wrap those, leaving your scripts to just do things like format reports.  Even with wrapped code, though, if I control the database, I can unwrap the code if I want and, even without unwrapping, I can see pretty much any SQL statement I want.  I've been able to point vendors at bugs in their wrapped code without needing to unwrap it.

Comment: yeah, you can't hide the SQL behind your reports, the DB will always know, and anyone with the right access to the database...

Comment: Does it have to be a SQL*Plus report, or can you use some other tool that would allow such obfuscation?

Comment: You can make wrap plsql procedure [to run sqlplus inside from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715856/is-it-possible-to-run-a-sqlplus-file-inside-a-stored-procedure/)